# Definite article in a list

Tags: articles

Would it be necessary to use any definite articles in this list?

There were many alternative theatres in London: Hackney Empire, Almeida, Half Moon, and King's Head.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would be normal to precede each with the definite article.

Comment: The only theatres I can think of that don't take _the_ are those that include a proper name in the possessive: _Wyndham's theatre_, _Wilton's music hall_; and optionally in cases where "theatre" comes first, followed by a qualifier: _(the) Theatre Royal_, _(the) Theatre in the Mill_, _(the) Theatre by the Lake_.